# Why is Subresource Integrity Only Required Sometimes

Tags: javascript, html

I have a vulnerability scan that is confusing me as to the nature of how Subresource Integrity works when loading scripts into the browser.

My page loads a number of scripts - for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
<link href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js" rel="preload" as="script">
```

My vulnerability scanner complains about subresource integrity on the second reference, but not the first.

Can anyone advise on why I don't also get a complaint about sub resource integrity on the first reference. google-analytics.com is obviously no more under my control than amazonaws.com so I'm not sure on what basis the warning arises

I am trying to understand why certain scripts result in a warning but others do not.

Comment: This feels like something you might be better off asking whoever built/provides the vulnerability scanner.

Comment: One thing of note is that `www.google-analytics.com` is demonstrably under google's control (let's ignore DNS hijacking for now) but AWS s3 does not validate what you name your buckets as, just that they are unique. You yourself can try to create an s3 folder called something like `https://s3.amazonaws.com/mailchimp-assets-official-no-lie/`. Just because it has `mailchimp` in its path does not mean mailchimp created that file.

Comment: Sure - I understand that some domains are likley higher trust than others. I'm not sure the browser would have any basis to make that determination however. I actually think the issue is that the second script is being loaded via a link tag rather than a script tag and that is why the scanner is treating them differently